# SVN repository change - move only selected dirs

Tags: svn

I would like to move only selected directories to new svn repository,
with history, but... I dont want to dump svn repository which is huge.

I have only external access to repository.

I have created script which gets all directories, finds first revision of each one, and
list of all revisions for selected directories.

Then consequently goes through that list. So I have revisions 32,...41, only those in which there were changes in my dirs.

Now I would like to commit changes every revision change to new repository.
Unfortunately svn_load_dirs.pl does not allow to pass comment.

Is there a way to commit my comment during svn_load_dirs.pl?

Just to be sure svn_load_dirs will make all changes in single revision?

Answer (score 0):

Why not first copy the entire repository using `svnsync`, and then use `svnadmin` and `svndumpfilter` to get to the relevant information?

Comment: The repository takes 20GB, and my directories takes only small part of it, so it is way faster to do this way. Moreover I don't have administration right on the destination server.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. It appears that the newest version of 
svn_load_dirs.pl has possibility of setting comment message.

Download trunk version of script from
[apache site](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/client-side/svn_load_dirs/svn_load_dirs.pl.in)

You can set the message using '-message' option.

Before using script change:
 my $svn = '@SVN_BINDIR@/svn';
to point to your svn binary, in my case: /usr/bin/svn